# node js allow access only from frontend

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to allow access only from my frontend and to restrict all others access from direct URL on API/postman and other things. I saw some examples here but I couldn't solve this thing.. This is my currently `app.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const companiesRoutes = require('./routes/companies-routes');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-routes');
const adsRoutes = require('./routes/ads-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');

const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions ={
  origin:'http://localhost:3000', 
  credentials:true,          
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}

app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'images')));
app.use('/uploads/videos', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'videos')));
app.use('/uploads/videos/thumb', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'videos/thumb')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT');
  next();
});

app.use('/api/companies', companiesRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/api/ads', adsRoutes);

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
  throw error;
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.file) {
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
});
```

and last `mongoose.connect` etc.

Maybe I did something wrong here but I cant realize where's the problem in this code. I got this example about **CORS** here from other topic but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Careful here: apps like Postman can (trivially) spoof requests to your back end, defeat CORS, and pretend to be from your front end. If user privacy is your concern, you'll want to use some sort of hard-to-guess random authorization cookie to enforce this restriction.

Comment: I did some things like users transactions and other things and i want to add security to it so only user can see them and access to them, what is the best way for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const companiesRoutes = require('./routes/companies-routes');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-routes');
const adsRoutes = require('./routes/ads-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');

const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
    methods: "GET, PUT" // add per need
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'images')));
app.use('/uploads/videos', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'videos')));
app.use('/uploads/videos/thumb', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'videos/thumb')));

app.use('/api/companies', companiesRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/api/ads', adsRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
  throw error;
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.file) {
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
});
```

**Note**: Visit this link [Handling CORS with Node.js](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/) if you interest a more better way to work with `CORS`

Comment: I updated my code because it didnt save my edit, can you look again at it end edit your code with example from my original post? Thanks for help

Comment: Okay let me see

Comment: Updated. Forgot to put a comma on `optionsSuccessStatus: 200,` this line ;)

Comment: Thanks alot, it looks like it work i tried with postman and i cant access it , but when i go directly in browsers like http://localhost:5000/api/users i got results is it ok?

Comment: Ya this is ok because `localhost:5000/api/users` this endpoint is actually your node-end app point. It's ok. Happ coding :)

Comment: Ya i see :) Last but not the least, make it as accepted if you think then mark it :)

Comment: Ye i did, it was only important for me because i made some for every user transaction or wallets and i ddint want to allow others users to watch in others wallets or transactions thats all i needed here, thanks one more time :]